# How to find an unknown Firebase document?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a friend/follower system with HTML and Firebase. I have made a page for adding new friends. When I press on the "Add Friend" button (picture below), I want the backend to find the document to the profile in the li, but I don't know how to find the exact document. Below you can also see my Firestore structure.

Javascript:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    db.collection('users').get().then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.docs)
        setupFindFriends(snapshot.docs)
    })

    const findfriends = document.querySelector('.findfriends');

    const setupFindFriends = (data) => {

        let html = '';
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const friend = doc.data();
            const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="name">${friend.Fullname}</div>
                <img class="friendpfp" src="${friend.pfpURL}">
                <button class="addfriend">Add friend</button>
            </li>
            `;
            html += li
        })

        findfriends.innerHTML = html;

    };

});
```

Firestore layout
[image: Firestore layout]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the document Id to an `addFriend()` function. Something along the following lines (untested):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    db.collection('users').get().then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.docs)
        setupFindFriends(snapshot.docs)
    })

    const findfriends = document.querySelector('.findfriends');

    const setupFindFriends = (data) => {

        let html = '';
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const friend = doc.data();
            const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="name">${friend.Fullname}</div>
                <img class="friendpfp" src="${friend.pfpURL}">
                <button class="addfriend" onclick="addFriend('${friendId}')">Add friend</button>
            </li>
            `;
            html += li
        })

        findfriends.innerHTML = html;

    };

});

function addFriend(friendId) {
    console.log(friendId);
 
    // Do something with friendId, e.g. create or update a Firestore doc, etc ... 
}
```

Comment: I've tried your answer now, and I get an error in the console:
`
Uncaught ReferenceError: HNJr68ZYXJXbA7v9n2jSHscXwSp1 is not defined
`
HNJr68ZYXJXbA7v9n2jSHscXwSp1 is the friendId

Comment: If I defined the function after findfriends.innerHTML = html; I get "addFriend is not defined". If I defined the function in a <script></script> tag in HTML I get the error above. No change after your update

Comment: Okay! I think it worked now. The function had to be defined in HTML and not in the JavaScript-file. Thanks!

Comment: See the update. Put the `addFriend()` function outside of the Auth listener.